# C Preprocessor Instructions (SQR-Funktion)

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Want to know how "11" is the answer of this c preprocessor instruction:

```
#define SQR(x) x*x

int main()
{
    SQR(2+3);
}
```

Comment: Does `11` print on the screen?

Comment: yes it does 2+3*2+3. but why? - no idea

Comment: 1. Because macro expansion is dumb textual replacement. 2. I asked does it print?, you said yes and I seriously doubt. Possibly it (main) returns 11. Reading macros from a C book should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the macro manually.

It will be `2+3*2+3` and this is evaluated as 11.

Comment: Why downvoted your answer? it is correct. Maybe a little ... minimal, but correct. Better add that this is the reason why is always better to add parenthesis around parameters. Try this: `#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))`

Comment: im just wondering why it does 2+3*2+3

Comment: @vamos Order of operations: multiplication first, then addition from left to right. 3 * 2 is 6, plus 2 is 8, plus 3 is 11.